# How to handle overlay/popup window using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate initial configuration(of my server) through webpage. After hitting my server ip https:/localhost:4443 and entering my credentials ,i get a window to change password(overlay/popup window).

Problem:- if i browse the same ip from another m/c or from another browser , i get a window over window i.e one more window over change password window([Please click the link to see the screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91420517/SelWd_popUpWindow.jpg)).

What i tried is to get the handle of the window but its not working, its providing one handle only.

**Its not frame also.

HTML code -- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91420517/Html_Code.JPG

Here's my code

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://localhost:4443/ControlPoint/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='name']")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginForm123']/div[6]/div[1]/div")).click();

    Set<String> winIds = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println("Total Windows --- " + winIds.size());    // its resulting the size as 1 which is not correct.
    Iterator<String> it = winIds.iterator(); 
    String mainWin=it.next();
    String changeWin=it.next();
    String shareWin =it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(shareWin);
    String warning = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4234]/div[1]/span")).getText();  // to get the text on 3 window
    System.out.println(warning);
```

How to resolve this issue .Please help. Any other way to click on buttons on window 3.

Comment: Why do you need multiple machines or browsers connecting to the server whilst you are trying to do initial configuration?

Comment: If the additional window is opened asynchronously, then possibly you are checking for it (with `getWindowHandles`) too early, before it has been created. You may need to try a few times with a wait in between.

Comment: Also, check that you have an updated version of Selenium/Webdriver - there seem to be some issues, with IE at least - see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/ULInjMbv5mU)

Comment: @DNA Thanks .. providing wait in between solved my issue.. I was checking getWindowsHandles() too early as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the additional window is opened asynchronously, then possibly you are checking for it (with `getWindowHandles()`) too early, before it has been created - this is a common issue with Selenium tests and asynchronous page updates.

If this is the issue, it can be solved by trying a few times with a wait in between, checking each time whether a new window has appeared.